# How to get correct rewrite URL with Azure and nginx?

Tags: azure, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an application running in a Docker container and listening for http traffic on port 5080. The server hosting this (and other) containers is running nginx as a reverse proxy. nginx listens for https traffic on 443 and when the server name matches, it proxies to http://127.0.0.1:5080/. So far so good.

The application in the container is using Azure-backed OpenID authentication. I believe I have the Azure configuration right, including setting up the Reply URL as `https://example.com/_renarde/security/oidc-success`.

When I attempt to log in, I get redirected to login.microsoft.com and provide my credentials. That goes well, so it tries to send me back to the application. However, I get this error:

> The redirect URI 'http://127.0.0.1:5080/j_oauth_callback' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application

It seems that the proxy address is leaking through. I found references to `proxy_redirect` for nginx, but that hasn't fixed the problem.

How do I get nginx to use the original domain name when the application sends a reply URL to Azure?

```
    server {
        server_name example.com; # managed by Certbot

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5080/;
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:5080/ https://example.com/;
            proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that you're setting proxied `Host` header incorrectly.

from the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#variables):

> **$proxy_host**
>
> name and port of a proxied server as specified in the proxy_pass directive;

so basically $proxy_host will be 127.0.0.1:5080, and so your application in the container will always think that it runs as 127.0.0.1:5080.

instead, you probably want to use `$http_host`, which is the value of the original "Host" request header. so basically you pass the same `Host` that was provided to nginx further to the application in container (i.e. example.com), so that application in the container knows about it.

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

Your application, when it redirects to login.microsoft.com, must provide `redirect_uri` query string parameter. My assumption is that it tries to point back to itself, and it picks the URL of itself from the request's `Host` header.

As for `proxy_redirect`, it would fire if your application redirected to itself, e.g. returned response with header `Location: http://127.0.0.1:5080/new_location`. But your application redirects to login.microsoft.com - i.e. returns smth. like `Location: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:5080/j_oauth_callback&...` - in which case it will not be rewritten.

> I believe I have the Azure configuration right, including setting up the Reply URL as https://example.com/_renarde/security/oidc-success.

Based on the error message, it seems like Reply URL means something different than the URL that whatever authentication library you're using sends to login.microsoft.com as the `redirect_uri`. Maybe it will redirect to that Reply URL **after** a successful authentication? (if this is the case, `proxy_redirect` will be useful).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I tried making this change, but then the app didn't redirect to Microsoft at all.

Comment: Hi Dave, unfortunately with the information you provide, it is very hard to understand what is going on there. I have several nginx deployments that do OAuth2 with Microsoft and everything works totally fine with the config I described in my answer (`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5080;` and `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` should be the only two lines you need). It would be great if you could specify what auth library you use, what response does your app return when it doesn't redirect, etc.

Comment: Btw one more problem I just noticed is that you do `proxy_pass http://localhost:5080/;` with the trailing slash, which means it will redirect specifically to the root path (`/`). I don't think it is intended as `/` location matches everything that starts with `/`, so you might want to change it to `proxy_pass http://localhost:5080;` (without the trailing slash) - in this case nginx will automatically add the current request path to the end of the URL.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I've tried the the `proxy_path` and `proxy_set_header` settings as you've described them. I think nginx is passing information along correctly, but the application behind the proxy isn't doing what it needs to. It either fails to redirect to Microsoft at all or sends a `localhost` reply URL. It's encouraging to hear this works for you. I'm upvoting your response because it's been helpful. I'll try focusing on the application behind the proxy.